# How do I enable LibreNMS Poller Cluster Health 1-minute polling?

Tags: networking, monitoring, polling

I had set up LibreNMS in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM. By default, LibreNMS polling interval is 5-minute, but instead I want to change the polling interval to 1-minute.

I have tried to configure: `/etc/cron.d/librenms` but does not seem to work. Seek HELP.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.librenms.org/), but I am just a newbie on LibreNMS, so, I really need help.